# Reading Microsoft xls and Libreoffice/openoffice spreadsheet using python

Tags: python

I want just read and write some records in a spreadsheet and I am writting a python code for that. However before I start I want to know whether I should use two separate python library/ways to read and write( Not analysis involved) in Microsoft word and Openoffice/Libreoffice?

Answer (score 0):

Please try my wrapper library `pyexcel` which read, write and manipulate csv, xls, xlsx, xlsm and ods formats using the same programming interface. [Documentation](http://pythonhosted.org//pyexcel/) and [code examples](https://github.com/chfw/pyexcel/tree/master/examples) are provided.

For open office spreadsheet(ods format), you would need to choose a plugin between [pyexcel-ods](https://github.com/chfw/pyexcel-ods) or [pyexcel-ods3](https://github.com/chfw/pyexcel-ods3) depending on your python version( 2 or 3)